# Random file directory "dropsecuredoc" gets added to my public_html

Tags: php, wordpress, security

I have a wordpress website that was hacked awhile back and was backed up and cleaned up. But everyday there's this "directory" called dropsecuredoc that gets added to my public_html (I usually delete it). It's completely empty, and I don't know what the deal is.

Is this maybe caused by wordfence or simple firewall? Is this some kind of backdoor that's adding it?

Anyone have any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: ***If*** it is malware, then maybe you should pre-create the directory and make its owner `root`. At least the botnet won't be able to use it, and you might get an access violation in the log to help track it. But then again, it may not be malware.

Comment: It could be malware; a Google search reveals nothing.